# Galaxy map generator always allows some star systems to touch

Tags: c#, procedural-generation

I am using procedural generation to create a `List<int[]>` where each `int[]` contains the x and y coordinates of a star system in a galaxy. I use a minimum distance argument to avoid placing star systems too close to each other. However, it doesn't seem to matter, and I always get at least a few star systems that touch.

*How can I make it so that, given a minimum distance of 2 or more, the coordinates generated will never touch?*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

/// <summary> 
/// Procedurally generates a new galaxy.
///
/// This class uses a relatively complex manner of ensuring no solar systems are
/// too close to each other. This is designed to allow slower hardware to handle
/// the generation fairly quickly. 
///
/// To achieve this, the program will break the given area of the galaxy into 
/// smaller squares. Each square will be given several solar systems that are at
/// least a user-given distance apart. Then each square will be placed within
/// the galaxy at the same user-given distance apart from each other. This 
/// ensures no solar systems are within the given distance from one another.
/// </summary>
public class GalGen
{
   /// <summary>
   /// Generates a new galaxy.
   /// 
   /// This generates a new galaxy by creating many small sections of the galaxy
   /// and combining them together.
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="galaxyHeight"> The height of the galaxy in sections. </param>
   /// <param name="galaxyWidth"> The width of the galaxy in sections. </param>
   /// <param name="sectionSize"> The height and width of galaxy sections in tiles. </param>
   /// <param name="minStars"> The lowest possible amount of stars per section. </param>
   /// <param name="maxStars"> The highest possible amount of stars per section. </param>
   /// <param name="minDistance"> Both the minimum distance between star 
   /// systems, and the distance of each sector from it's neighbors and the
   /// borders of the galaxy. </param>
   /// <returns> A List<int[]> of (x, y) star system locations </returns>
   public static List<int[]> 
   generate(int galaxyHeight, int galaxyWidth, int sectionSize, int minStars, int maxStars, int minDistance)
   {
      Random rand = new Random();
      List<int[]> galaxy = new List<int[]>(2_500);

      for (int x = 0; x < galaxyWidth; x++)
      {
         for (int y = 0; y < galaxyHeight; y++)
         {
            // randomly determine the amount of star systems in the section
            int stars = rand.Next(minStars, maxStars + 1);
            // create the section
            List<int[]> section = createSection(sectionSize, minDistance, stars);
            // adjust the section's position according to it's placement in the galaxy
            section = adjustSystemPosition(section, sectionSize, x, y);
            // add the star system's coordinates to the galaxy
            galaxy = galaxy.Concat(section).ToList();
         }
      }

      return galaxy;
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// Adjusts the position of the star systems in a section according to their
   /// position in the galaxy, as indicated by the y and x arguments.
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="section"> The section to modify. </param>
   /// <param name="x"> The amount of sections to the left of the section argument. </param>
   /// <param name="y"> The amount of sections above the section argument. </param>
   /// <returns> A List<int[]> of (x, y) star system coordinates. </returns>
   public static List<int[]> 
   adjustSystemPosition(List<int[]> section, int sectionSize, int x, int y)
   {
      for (int i = 0; i < section.Count; i++)
      {
         int xPos; 
         int yPos; 

         // adjust for tile size
         xPos = section[i][0] << 5; // 32
         yPos = section[i][1] << 5; // 32

         // adjust for section position
         xPos += (x * sectionSize) << 5; // 32
         yPos += (y * sectionSize) << 5; // 32

         // adjust for section borders
         xPos += x << 5; // 32
         yPos += y << 5; // 32

         section[i] = new int[] {xPos, yPos};
      }

      return section;
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// Generates a small, square, section of the galaxy. 
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="sectionSize"> The height and width of the galaxy section. </param>
   /// <param name="minDistance"> The minimum distance between star systems. </param>
   /// <param name="stars"> The amount of stars to create. </param>
   /// <returns> A List<int[]> of (x, y) star system locations. </returns>
   private static List<int[]> 
   createSection(int sectionSize, int minDistance, int stars)
   {
      Random rand = new Random();
      List<int[]> section = new List<int[]>(stars);

      // determine the first star system's location
      int x = rand.Next(0, sectionSize + 1);
      int y = rand.Next(0, sectionSize + 1);
      int[] location = new int[] {x, y};
      section.Add(location);

      for(int i = (stars - 1); i > 0; i--)
      {
         // create new star coordinates
         x = rand.Next(0, sectionSize + 1);
         y = rand.Next(0, sectionSize + 1);
         location = new int[] {x, y};

         // avoid locations that would put it too close to other stars

         for(int j = 0; j < section.Count; j++)
         {
            if (findDistance(location, section[j]) < minDistance)
            {
               j = 0; // restart loop
               // find new potential star coordinates
               x = rand.Next(0, sectionSize);
               y = rand.Next(0, sectionSize);
               location = new int[] {x, y};
            }
         }

         section.Add(location);
      }

      return section;
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// Finds the distance between two stars.
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="star1"> The coordinates of the first star </param>
   /// <param name="star2"> The coordinates of the second star. </param>
   /// <returns> The distance between the two stars. </returns>
   private static double findDistance(int[] star1, int[] star2)
   {
      double exponent1 = Math.Pow((star1[0] - star2[0]), 2.0);
      double exponent2 = Math.Pow((star1[1] - star2[1]), 2.0);

      return Math.Sqrt(exponent1 + exponent2);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this section:

```
for(int j = 0; j < section.Count; j++)
{
    if (findDistance(location, section[j]) < minDistance)
```

You iterate through all of them and regenerate if they are close. However it might just generate coordinates that collide with a previous one.

Do this instead:
(Minimal change intended for demonstration purposes. A proper solution would be different. Also if there is no room it will never finish!)

```
for(int i = (stars - 1); i > 0; i--)
{
   do {
      bool collisionFound = false;
      // create new star coordinates
      x = rand.Next(0, sectionSize + 1);
      y = rand.Next(0, sectionSize + 1);
      location = new int[] {x, y};

      // avoid locations that would put it too close to other stars

      for(int j = 0; j < section.Count; j++)
      {
         if (findDistance(location, section[j]) < minDistance)
         {
            collisionFound = true;
            break;
         }
      }
   } while (collisionFound);
   section.Add(location);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!